# Universal header to include in C language

Tags: c

I am new to C language, and was wondering if there is a universal header that can be included at top of main function . In Java it is very easy just do ctrl+shift+o in eclipse and it imports packages for you. But in C, I have to google every time and add it. Sometimes, I don't even know what library to include. 
Thank you very much .

Comment: _Java_ is not what's making your life easier, _Eclipse_ is. Java will equally complain that you haven't imported something, without telling you what. You might want to ask for an IDE that does the same for C as Eclipse does for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *universal* header -- since parsing every header takes time, and there are thousands (if not millions) of headers available, there is no way to include them all into every compilation unit. You wouldn't want to, since 99.9% of them wouldn't be *used* and would only needlessly bloat the end executable with static allocations.

Every standardized function will tell you the headers you need to include at the top of its manpage; for example, from `malloc(3)`:

```
NAME
   calloc, malloc, free, realloc - Allocate and free dynamic
   memory

SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
   void *malloc(size_t size);
   void free(void *ptr);
   void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

Thus you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` in your project, and there's the prototypes for you to see.

If you want a quick way to see the manpages, you can configure your IDE to show them to you quickly. The default keybinding for <kbd>K</kbd> in `vim` is to load the manpage for the function under the cursor -- but, since it uses the default manpage search order, it can sometimes find the wrong page. (On `printf`, for example, it loads `printf(1)` rather than `printf(3)`. Annoying. The `MANSECT` environment variable described in `man(1)` can be used to change this behavior to show you `3` before `1`, if you wish.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal header, but you can certainly make one for your application, and include it in all your files. If you are not sure what file to include for a function that you need to call, you can use `man` command on UNIX. For example,

```
man 3 printf
```

shows this:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```

If you stay with it for enough time, you usually remember the "mapping" of functions to headers relatively quickly.

Comment: You can only use `man printf -s 3` on Linux or GNU-based systems (and only if you don't set POSIXLY_CORRECT in the environment).  All sane places require options like `-s 3` before arguments such as `printf`, leading to `man -s 3 printf` for portability.  However, ISTR there are systems that don't support the `-s 3` notation and you are sometimes better off using the `man 3 printf` notation.  Having said that, I don't immediately have an example of such a system; it may be that things have changed with the more recent releases and I'm remembering hiccups from long ago.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting! I've been using this syntax on my mac for years, without knowing the shorter `man 3 printf` notation. Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrapping problem... 'printf' - not the most obvious name.  'calloc', 'strcmp' - no better.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single header that is all-encompassing.

All else apart, any such header for MS Windows would be wrong for Unix, and any such header for Unix would be wrong for Windows.  Even on Unix, should the universal header include all the X11 headers?  What about the OpenSSL headers?  What about the POSIX threads headers?  Other POSIX headers?

You need to learn where to go to find the information for any given function that you need to use.  On Unix, the classic resource was the 'man page' (meaning 'manual page', typically formatted with the '`-man`' troff/nroff macro package).  These days, I tend to use the web: for example, I find [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) man pages at The Open Group.

(Note that a header is separate from a library; there may be many headers used by the functions in a single library.  See the Standard C Library as an illustration.)

Comment: Incidentally, Debian and Ubuntu and other derived systems have the POSIX manpages available in the `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev` packages -- this makes it easy to compare `man 3 pthread_cancel` vs `man 3posix pthread_cancel`. I _love_ having both at my fingertips.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I suppose you could create one, but that would slow your compiles down quite a bit. Some IDEs might help you find the include files.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Eclipse to automatically insert various header files you use often. But: if you want to learn C I would suggest that you do that job of finding which ones to include.

It's as with all learning. Learn by doing — learn by repetition.

The standard C library is not *that* huge — and the header files are intuitively named and have a manageable list of standard functions.

Have a list like [this](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html) available and read it. Read it when you'll need an include etc.

When you feel you really know when and what to include. Automate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are including a header file because you are using an interface defined in the header file; not because there is a standard set to include.  So, how do you determine what interface you need?  There are two basic options:

1. Find either the header files or descriptions of the header files and look through them to learn of the interfaces, or
2. Use 'apropos search_term' or 'man interface_function'.

As a beginner, option #1 would be a good start — look in `/usr/include` or find a book named 'The C Standard Library' (or something similar).

Comment: Be cautious about learning how to write headers from the material in `/usr/include`.  These headers typically contain a lot of cruft accumulated over many years and many versions of many standards, and try to deal with them all.  To do so, they are seldom models of clarity; they are often some of the most intricate and opaque rats' nests of `#ifdef` and `#define`.  That said, they are the place to look to find out whether and how a particular function is defined; it just isn't always obvious from first (or second, and sometimes one hundredth) glance which definition is used.

Answer (score 0):

A good reference manual (such as [this one](http://www.careferencemanual.com/)) will have an appendix listing all of the library functions and their associated header file.  You can also check the on-line [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Chapter 7 for a similar listing.